# Lightning component to detect data change

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm working on a lightning component for Contact object. Every time a new Case record is created, I need to display total number of newly created cases on the Contact lightning action.

From component perspective, I can call a server action to get total cases, but I'm not sure how a server event (e.g. new case creation) will update the client side lightning component attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper way to listen server events like create/update/delete, is to subscribe for those events using the Streaming API.

[Here's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_vfp_create_VF_page.htm), an working example how to use Streaming API in VF page.
Unlike Visualforce which has `$Api.sessionid`, we don't have such things in LC.
Since LC does not have an sessionid exposed is discussed in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/73896/20830) question and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/101222/20830) too, there's no straightdown approach to solve this.

As a workaround, you can get the sessionId using the from the controller using approach mentioned in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73917/20830).(Still its an hacky way)

So I did some digging and found a example LC using Streaming API in [github](https://github.com/mshanemc/lightningStreamer) thanks to @ShaneMcLaughlin.

I tried to implement a bit simple version and it worked fine in my org.

**StreamingTest.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="StreamingCtrl">
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/streamingapi/js/cometd.js,/resource/streamingapi/js/jquery-1.5.1.js,/resource/streamingapi/js/json2.js,/resource/streamingapi/js/jquery.cometd.js"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="topic" type="string" required="true" />
</aura:component>
```

**StreamingTestController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('doing init on streamer');

        // Retrieve the session id and initialize cometd
        var sessionAction = component.get("c.sessionId");

        sessionAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state  === "SUCCESS") {
                var sessionId = response.getReturnValue();
                var authstring = "OAuth " + sessionId;
                console.log(sessionId);
                //authenticate to the Streaming API
                $.cometd.init({
                    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/36.0/',
                    requestHeaders: { Authorization: authstring },
                    appendMessageTypeToURL : false
                });
                $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/'+component.get("v.topic"), function (message){
                    //print message when new contact is created
                    console.log(message);
                    console.log(message.data.sobject);

                });

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(sessionAction);        
    }
})
```

**PushTopic**

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'contactnew';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 37.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```