# Lightning Components: how to use events to detect record updates?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have a custom Lightning Component sitting on a Flexipage for e.g. Account. Now I want to register an handler, which will be invoked each time, the record is updated. Updates might happen via

- standard Record Detail component on the same Flexipage
- other custom components on the same Flexipage
- triggers

What's the best way to detect and handle as many of these updates as possible?

I've tried so far:

```
<aura:handler name="onUpdated" event="force:recordUpdated"action="{!c.events}" />
<aura:handler name="onSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.events}"/>
```

with

```
events : function(cmp, evt, hlp){
    console.log('EVENTS :: ',evt.getName(),evt.getParams());
},
```

but nothing in the console so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm) to handle the record changes, but its still in Developer Preview which means that you won't be able to use it in a Production or Sandbox org.

Next option is to use Streaming API, to listen for record updates you can find it [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/145119/20830). Still I feel it's hacky way.

Final option though I don't like either,

1) Regularly poll the server for the record  using `window.setInterval()`.

2) Compare with local version of the record in the client.

3) If record has changed, refresh data in the component.

Comment: setInterval is the best method we've found so far. Updates on any one specific record are pretty rare, so we just poll the server every 30 seconds. Far as I can tell, we're not pinged for API usage with this technique (at least, for now), so it works out well.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've added a new answer on force:refreshView which could possibly reduce the need of setInterval(). Have you ever tried that and found use-cases where it was insufficient? Would be interested what aspects are not coverd by force:refreshView to be aware of in my implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Actually I'm using the event force:refreshView which is doing what I want:

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.forceRefreshViewHandler}"/>
```

and in the controller

```
forceRefreshViewHandler : function(cmp, evt, hlp){
    // your logic here
},
```

If my stuff is making an update, which the flexipage should update on, I'm firing the very same event

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

Tricky part is, if two components are updating each others: then you have to set a flag or something to prevent endless loops.

Lots of Salesforce Standard components are firing and listening for this event, so it's pretty useful.

**Caveats**

- updates made by triggers or API integrations probably get NOT detected
- updates made by components not firing force:refreshView are not detected

Comment: I just tried this and I couldn't make it to work. Basically, I have a component that sits on Account's Flexipage and listens for this `force:refreshView` event, and it never catches it. Even though I see it being fired in the Lightning Inspector on chrome. BTW, I'm trying to catch some event that will let me know that the standard Quick Action has been saved/closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this.  Seems to do the job adequately for me on record pages.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm

Doesn't explicitly refresh a specific component but it does refresh the page's components when you update the underlying record via your own code / controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PushTopic for that. All you have to do is create a push Topic in lightning Components. Not best of Solution But can work.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/working_with_pushtopics.htm