# Tell a component to update its' content when a related record is added on the same record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sobject, event

I have a **Lightning Component** in a **Record Page** on **Order** object, and whenever I add a product (new **OrderItem** is created) in the order, I'd like to somehow notify the component to update its' content.

Just so things make more sense, my component has to show the total weight of the products.

All I need here is directions on how to accomplish this.
Ideally I'd want to be able to fire custom events and on component have a listener. Which I have no idea if it's even possible.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155478/lightning-components-how-to-use-events-to-detect-record-updates/155535), if it helps.

Comment: I did learn something from the component-to-component, but still can't find anything about object changes event to component

Comment: This answer helped a lot  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217713/58347  Thanks @JayantDas