# how to connect to websocket in Lightning?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

I am  using Leapjs external library and trying to execute a simple Leapjs function : loop in lightning component.

I got content security policy error which goes like this

> Refused to connect to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6437/v3.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

now  in documentation it says that XHR and websockets can only be called by same domain. (mostly it is lightning.force.com but my domain is 127.0.0.1:6437.

I have also added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self'"/>
```

in my code

any workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested WebSockets in Open CTI adapter url. It works perfectly fine.
Change the ws:// uri as per your setup in below source code.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://na11.salesforce.com/support/api/28.0/interaction.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var callback = function (response) {
           if (response.result) {
              alert('Screen pop was set successfully.');
           }
           else {
              alert('Screen pop failed.' + result.error);
           }
        };
       function screenPop() {
                //Invokes API method
                sforce.interaction.screenPop('/001x0000003DGQR', true, callback);
        }
</script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var webSocket;
            var data = "";

            function openSocket()
            {
                // Open server socket
                if (webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) {
                    alert("WebSocket is already opened");
                    return;
                }

                webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/sample/sampleendpoint");

                if (webSocket === undefined)
                {
                    alert("Error creating socket...");
                    return;
                }

                webSocket.onopen = function()
                {
                    alert("in onopen callback");
                }

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event)
                {
                    alert("in onmessage callback   " + data);
                }

                webSocket.onclose = function()
                {
                    alert("in onclose callback");
                }
            }

        </script>

</head>
<body>
       <button onclick="openSocket();">Open Socket</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known limitation with lightning currently](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-to-call-a-salesforce-rest-url-from-lightning-component)

However I see that your script is trying to make the call to a third party URL .You will need to identify the script and try and make the callout via apex .From lightning due to security limitations no XHR will be allowed .

The other workaround will be to proxy this via the Visualforce .There is a neat article on how to do this

[Blog article from developer force](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-to-call-a-salesforce-rest-url-from-lightning-component)

Also if the webserver is just returning a JSON without any processing you may download the file and keep inside static resource .

Comment: I have Leap motion controller and it feeds data to websocket as json. Its is very dynamic data as per my hand movements. it cannot be static

Comment: You may need to go via vf proxy..Looks no other alternative to me..

Comment: I tried using VF , i have another juggling . there is reference to local storage in in  leapjs library and VF is not liking it!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I just tripped upon this today, but it looks like CSP Trusted Sites now supports Websockets.  Notice in the [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) that `wss` is now supported.  Finally!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when this went live as there's still an [open idea on this topic](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E5nmQAC), but WebSockets are [now supported in CSP Trusted Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) settings.

Add you `wss://` endpoint via Setup -> CSP Trusted Site and you should be good to go.