# Video in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to display a video in a lightning component:

```
<video width="400" controls="controls">
  <source src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=ABCDEFGHIJ" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

I'm running into the below error:

Refused to load media from '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=ABCDEFGHIJ' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self'".

I could not find any solutions on how to fix this, the same error when I'm trying a youtube or vimeo video. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The current CSP employed by Lightning will not allow you to do this. [See this thread for more information](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-to-call-a-salesforce-rest-url-from-lightning-component). [Here's the official documentation on Lightning Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security).

Comment: You'd have to upload your file as a Static Resource instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But a Static Resource can only be 5MB, so this means we wont be allowed to use any content from AWS S3 as well, right?

Comment: Just a food for thought.. lightning has support for HTML5 and the Source src tag that you have used above does support data-uri  attributes, so something like  <video controls> <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDJpc29....../l/L+X8v5AAAAMgfDg==">  should work, where the data:video is the base64 conversion for the video that you can get from the AWS S3 in your @Aura-Enabled methods .. Not sure for the performance and feasibility, but just saying its possible.