# Plugging React JS app into lightning community

Tags: lightning, lightning-community, iframe, lightning-container, react

I have created a react.js application where I have used SLDS for my styling and I have also installed Lightning container module to make direct API calls to APEX code in my org. 
I want to plug the component into my lightning component and then pull it to lightning community. 
I understand that, to embed react.js app into lightning component, i need to use lightning:container which is not supported in Lightning Communities.
IS there any other way I can plug my react into communties. or embedding my react to VF and then to communties is the only way out now ?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the introduction of lightning:container, this could be done using VisualForce in Lightning Communities to host an iframe:

> In order to use another framework as part of a package that uses Lightning, please use an iframe or Visualforce container until approved Lightning containers are published.

```
<div>
    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/GoogleMap'}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="376"/>
</div>
```

which communicates with your external component via HTML5 postMessage:

```
({
    recordChangeHandler : function(component, event) {
        var id = event.getParam("recordId");
        component.set("v.recordId", id);
        var service = component.find("service");
        service.reloadRecord();
    },
    
    propertyChangeHandler : function(component, event) {
        var property = component.get("v.property");
        var vfOrigin = "https://" + component.get("v.vfHost");
        var vfWindow = component.find("vfFrame").getElement().contentWindow;
        vfWindow.postMessage(property, vfOrigin);
    }
})
```

[image: iframe postmessage VF => Lightning]

**References**

- [How to call a Salesforce REST URL from Lightning Component? - Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-to-call-a-salesforce-rest-url-from-lightning-component/55380)
- [GitHub - ccoenraets/lc-vf-communication: Example of bidirectional communication between Lightning Components and Visualforce pages](https://github.com/ccoenraets/lc-vf-communication)
- [Use Visualforce in Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5)